# How to read data from StreamingOutput

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-rs

I have a restful webservice. I am thinking of calling a method from another method in the class. Is it possible? If so, how do I read the content of streaming output in example below? Also, I need both functions separately so that I can return binary files or display text of text files

```
@Path("/base")
public class Base{

    @GET
    @Path("/base/func1")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    public Response func1(){
        final String some_outfilename = "test.pdf";
        StreamingOutput st = new StreamingOutput(){
            @Override
            public void write(OutputStream os) throws IOException{
                Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));
                writer.write("test");
                writer.flush();
            }
        };
        return Response.ok(stream, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).header("content-disposition","attachment; filename =" + some_outFilename).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    @Path("/base/func2")
    public Response func2(){
        //I want to call func1() from here, like
        //StreamingOutput st = (StreamingOutput)func1().getEntity();
        //But how do I get the "test" written inside??
        //Once obtained I can return it as response
    }
}
```

---

EDIT #1:
func1() does have a return statement. I put it in later (sorry). func2() is also supposed to have a return statement.. I haven't put it because I do not understand how to structure it.

Answer (score 2):

`func1` does not return anything, not even `st`.

You should move the common code that you want to use from both `func1` and `func2` to a third `private` method. This method should return something that can then be wrapped in a `StreamingOutput` instance.

Comment: I'm terribly extremely sorry.. I did mean to put a return statement in func1. I have put it there. In func2, there is no return, because I do not see what structure to return, but it also intends to return a response